# Dealing with rationals in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, probability

```py
>>> Rational((0.5*1/2)/(0.5*1/2+0.2))
2501999792983609/4503599627370496
```

So I want this to give me a fraction of 5/9, is it possible to get that in python?

Comment: Write your question here rather than putting a link to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `nsimplify` instead of `Rational` or else use the `limit_denominator` on the `Rational`:

[image]